# How to assure a PID from its module?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring such that every submodule of a free $R$-module is free. Prove that $R$ is a PID.

We know that "PID" is principal Ideal Domain.
How to prove the question? Thanks!!

Comment: Hint: Note that each ideal of $R$ is a submodule of $R$ as an $R$-module.

Comment: In addition to what Johannes Kloos explained: any two elements of an ideal are linearly dependent over $R$ (need commutativity here).